# Bootstrap Datepicker control in ng-grid cellTemplate "AngularJS"

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, ng-grid

I am using ng-grid and binding bootstrap calender control onto ng-grid as follows

```
 $scope.EmployeeGridOptions.columnDefs = [
{
               field: 'requestStartDate', displayName: 'Start Date',
               cellTemplate: '<input ng-click="open($event,row.rowIndex)" 
ng-model="row.entity.requestStartDate" datepicker-append-to-body=true datepicker-popup="MM/dd/yyyy" is-opened="false"></input>'
}
]
```

I want to open the data picker control when user click on textbox. Right now datepicker is getting opened all the time. Is there is any way to open an instance of datepicker when open function is fired.

```
$scope.calandar=function($event,row){
            $event.preventDefault();
            $event.stopPropagation();

            $scope.opened2 = true;

        }
```

Help with regards to this is highly appreciated..Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try `ng-focus` instead of `ng-click`.

Comment: Thank you..I am able to get to the event with ng-focus/ng-click but how do I just pop up one calendar control and attach the selected value in ng-model (I do not want to associate calendar control onto each row) just want to open when the event fires.

Answer (score 0):

Since I had multiple calendar controls on a web page. Built in angular does not have calendar controls. I do not have paging on the web page. Bootstrap calendar controls are very expensive. Hence used Jquery calendar control to by pass performance issues and functionality. Thank you.

```
 $scope.OpenDatePicker = function (row, rowId) {
             lastId = rowId + row.entity.employeeId;
             position = $("#" + lastId).offset();

             $("#dtpicker").val($("#" +lastId).val());

            $('#dtpicker').datepicker('option', 'minDate', $("#PayPeriodEndDateMin").val());
            $('#dtpicker').datepicker('option', 'maxDate', $("#PayPeriodEndDate").val());

            $(".ui-datepicker-trigger").trigger("click");
        }
```